# DVR with the ability to record "all instances of this show"; don't care about streaming

Tags: video-capture, dvr

I have a [TiVo Premiere](http://www3-stg.tivo.com/products/tivo-premiere/premiere-specs.html) that seems to be in the process of dying, so I'd like to replace it with another DVR (needn't be TiVo, and refurbished is fine).  Less-expensive options are preferable but I want a box that I can just plug in -- I don't want to build my own Linux box for this.

Required:

- Works with Verizon FiOS with a multi-stream CableCard.
- Wired ethernet.
- Programming by show, including by season: "record $series (all season)" or "record $show (that's on next week)".  The device (or its associated program guide) should do the right thing if something causes programming to run 5 minutes late that night.
- No monthly fees.  A one-time fee for program-guide services (like TiVo has) is fine, and considered to be part of the cost of the device.
- Hard drive can hold at least 50 hours of HD recordings.
- HDMI out.  (I assume they all have that these days.)

Nice to have:

- Works with antenna.
- Two tuners.
- Supports additional external hard drive (USB).
- Android app to function as remote control.

Do not care about:

- Streaming services.  (My Roku is just fine for that.)
- Music, photos, web.
- Paid services (video on demand to watch a hot movie or sporting event, for instance).
- 4K output.
- Support for multiple TVs.